# Spring boot, environment specific properties location

Tags: java, maven, properties, spring-boot

I can see many posts regarding environment specific properties, but none of them is quite solving my problem.

I'm working on my spring boot app, which will have say two profiles dev/live.

I want my project to have the following structure:

```
--deployment
  --dev
    --myapp.properties
  --live
    --myapp.properties
--src
  --main
    --java
    --resources
  --test
    --java
```

I know that if I had two `application.properties` in my resources folder, say `application-live.properties` and `application-dev.properties` I'd be able to tell maven which one to pick at application start time using:

```
Dspring.profiles.active=profile_name
```

But I don't like name of this generic properties file. So I found this way to tell the application where to look for profile specific properties in `/deployment/<profile>/`.

I did it using Maven build task configuration:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>deployment/${environment}</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

This is going to search for resources in `deployment/<profile>` and include them. Good thing is that Maven finds the correct environmental property files, but unfortunately it includes them in `target/classes/myapp.properties` which seems invisible for Spring Boot? How can I tell Maven to place it in the same directory as `application.properties`or alternately how can I tell Spring Boot to find it where it is at the moment?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I tell Maven to place it in the same directory as application.propertiesor alternately how can I tell Spring Boot to find it where it is at the moment?

1) you don't need to modify Maven settings because it places config file to the right place: `target/classes` is the root of the classpath, because all files from this directory will copied into the `WEB-INF/classes` directory of you WAR/JAR file.

2) to change name of the properties file from you can use `spring.config.name` property by explicitly passing it as `-Dspring.config.name=myapp` or as environment variable `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=myapp`. More information you can find in the [Change the location of external properties of an application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties) chapter of the official documentation.

Comment: What if I want to have multiple properties file, not just one? And I one one of each type for every environment.

Comment: Multiple `application.properties` files are not supported. But you can define common parameters in the `application.properties` and other profile specific parameters in the `application-{profile}.properties` file.

Comment: Alright, I decided to go for the 'application-{profile}.properties' solution. I still have these profile specific properties under my '/deployment'. Thanks.